# Triple Boot with Linux, OS X Yosemite and Windows 7 on iMac

Tags: windows-7, linux, macos, mac, boot

I have a iMac 2015 with Retina 5K display and OS X Yosemite installed. I intend to install Linux Mint as well as Windows 7 or in other sense triple boot all these three OS.

I did find some instructions here and hopefully I'll manage from there

https://superuser.com/questions/776211/how-stable-is-a-triple-boot-setup-for-os-x-windows-7-and-ubuntu-linux

The real concern is that once I am done installing all the three OS on the iMac, is there anyway I can create a backup Image of the hard drive with all the installations on it so that I can just restore the image on other systems I intend to install them on later ?

Comment: I see no reason at all why you shouldn't be able to do so. As long as you boot from a LiveCD/USB-based imaging solution and completely image the drive including the MBR/GPT, you should be able to restore the same to another drive. Just remember that if those "other systems" are drastically different in terms of hardware you're bound to have problems with getting the OSes to run (especially Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you recommend me any such program that would do the task on iMac. Also I would be restoring the image on Imac itself and not any other systems.

Comment: You can ask for recommendations [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Use a VM like VMware workstation and you will be able to do the same